# How to push navigation in appdelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have successfully implemented push notification but how can I  push navigation from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method.

**My Code**

***Appdelegate code***

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    sleep(3);
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self registerForPushNotification:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
            [self handlePush:application forRemoteNotification:dictionary];
        }
    }
 [self setupMainPage];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)setupMainPage
{
    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"LoggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstLaunch"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

            IntroVC *introView = [[IntroVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroVC" bundle:nil];
            self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:introView];
            [self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            LoginVC *loginVC = [[LoginVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HomeVC *homeView = [[HomeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeVC" bundle:nil];
        self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeView];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
}

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
        NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
        NSLog(@"USER INFO - %@",userInfo);
        for (id key in userInfo)
        {
            NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
        }

        [self handlePush:application forRemoteNotification:userInfo];
    }





  -(void)handlePush:(UIApplication *)application forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
        //NSString *pushType = [[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"type"] lowercaseString];

        pushAlert = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        pushType = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"type"];
        NSInteger pushBadge = [[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];
        strReciverId = [CommonUtils getNotNullString:[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"receiver_id"]];
        if (pushBadge > 0) {
            [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:pushBadge];
        }
        // aceept request
        if ([pushType isEqualToString:@"palrequest"])
        {
            [CommonUtils alertViewDelegateWithTitle:AlertTitle
                                        withMessage:pushAlert
                                          andTarget:self
                                    forCancelString:@"View Invitation"
                               forOtherButtonString:@"Cancel"
                                            withTag:101];
        }
}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    if (alertView.tag == 101)
    {
             MyMatchesVC *myMatchesVC = [[MyMatchesVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMatchesVC" bundle:nil];
             myMatchesVC.strType = pushType;
             [navigationController pushViewController:myMatchesVC animated:YES];

    }

}
```

push working perfect but my issue is when i push then automatically change my rootview.

my app flow

1. login to app then I have changed my root view  (Homeview controller)
2. now I  got notification from other user then i view invitation tap then push to my matches.
3. now i back from my match then it's changed to login

need this result

- > when i back from mymatch then pop to home view controller

Please help me to  solve this issue.

Comment: what you want to achieve ? not getting your question exactly!

Comment: push working from didReceiveRemoteNotification but my root view changed  automatically

Comment: check my appdelegate code

Comment: Why are you calling the [self handlePush:] before setting the root-view [self setupMainPage];?

Comment: becz notifcation have some palyod then i need to push

Comment: You want to set `HomeVC` as root viewcontroller after pushing `MyMatchesVC` ?

Comment: so do you want to push `MyMatchesVC` on home view controller ?

Comment: please my answer and let me know the updates.

Comment: checking wait...

Comment: Use showViewController method :)

--- [self.window.rootViewController showViewController:myMatchesVC sender:self]; ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this! Simple solution :)

```
if (alertView.tag == 101)
{
         MyMatchesVC *myMatchesVC = [[MyMatchesVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMatchesVC" bundle:nil];
         myMatchesVC.strType = pushType;
           [self.window.rootViewController showViewController:myMatchesVC sender:self];


}
```

// If you already the MyMatchVC. Please follow below style .

```
  UINavigationController *snNavShareVC = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSArray *viewControllers = snNavShareVC.viewControllers;
    UIViewController *findViewController = nil;
    for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[vc  class]);
        if ([MyMatchesVC class] == [vc class]) {
            findViewController = vc;
        }
    }
    if (findViewController) {
        [findViewController updateView:pushType]; // Write method to update view
    } else {
        MyMatchesVC *myMatchesVC = [[MyMatchesVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMatchesVC" bundle:nil];
        myMatchesVC.strType = pushType;
        [self.window.rootViewController showViewController:myMatchesVC sender:self];

    }
```

// Try this to add stack viewcontroller in navigation controller.

```
    ChatListVC *chatList = [[ChatListVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChatListVC" bundle:nil]; ChatDetailsVC *chatDetail = [[ChatDetailsVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChatDetailsVC" bundle:nil]; 
    chatDetail.strReceiverId = strReciverId; 
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [self.navController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    [controllers addObject:chatList];
    [controllers addObject:chatDetail]; 
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers];
```

Comment: wait i checking

Comment: Ok.. Please let me know once you tested with above code!! :)

Comment: it's working fine but I am already in same view controller  now when push notification comes it again push same view on which i am currently

Comment: it's working fine but my another view controller not dispaly

Comment: ChatListVC *chatList = [[ChatListVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChatListVC" bundle:nil];

                    ChatDetailsVC *chatDetail = [[ChatDetailsVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChatDetailsVC" bundle:nil];

                    chatDetail.strReceiverId = strReciverId;
                    NSMutableArray *controllers = [self.navController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
                    [controllers addObject:chatList];
                    [controllers addObject:chatDetail];
                    [self.window.rootViewController showViewController:chatDetail sender:self];

Comment: If you are going to push, then why you are trying to add to the list?
 [controllers addObject:chatDetail]; 

Also, this is not your question too!!! You got the answers regarding your quesiton!!

Comment: when i pop  view from chat then display chat list then i pop on chatlist display home view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146833/discussion-between-vignesh-kumar-and-maulik).

Comment: [self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers];
 not working for multiple controller

Comment: Check discussion

Comment: @Maulik, Please see the chat message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call the `[self setupMainPage];` before calling the `[self handlePush:` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    sleep(3);
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self setupMainPage];

    [self registerForPushNotification:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
            [self handlePush:application forRemoteNotification:dictionary];
        }
     }

     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
 }
```

Update the alertView `clickedButtonAtIndex` and use the `self.navController` instead of using  `(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (alertView.tag == 101)
    {
       MyMatchesVC *myMatchesVC = [[MyMatchesVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMatchesVC" bundle:nil];
       myMatchesVC.strType = pushType;
       [self.navController pushViewController:myMatchesVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: using this line navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController ... my root view changed automatically

Comment: my rootview changed when i push from appdelegate. using this line  navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController

Comment: navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController 

i used this line for pushing my view controller

Comment: update your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code in the question,please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain login or logout state, with this you can judge where you have to pop, if you are logout then you have to `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` and if you are login then your have to `popToViewController: animated:` your home page

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
if (isLogin) {
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
else{
    NSArray *arrView = [navController childViewControllers];
    for (id vc in arrView) {
        if ([vc  isKindOfClass: [Homeview class]]) {
            [navController popToViewController:vc animated:NO];
            break;
        }
}

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];
[navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do as you asked like When you back from `MyMatchesVC` then pop to `HomeVC` controller, You need to Push `MyMatchesVC` From `HomeVC` otherwise if you push `MyMatchesVC` directly from root navigation controller which have `LoginVC` as root view Controller so you will not get HomeVC as Root. For that you have to do like as under.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

        if (alertView.tag == 101)
        {
                 HomeVC *homeView = [[HomeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeVC" bundle:nil];
                 navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:introView];

                 MyMatchesVC *myMatchesVC = [[MyMatchesVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMatchesVC" bundle:nil];
                 myMatchesVC.strType = pushType;
                 [navigationController pushViewController:myMatchesVC animated:YES];

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyMatchesVC *myMatchesVC = [[MyMatchesVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMatchesVC" bundle:nil];
myMatchesVC.strType = pushType;
[((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController) setViewControllers:@[((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController, myMatchesVC] animated:YES];
```

for go to visible viewcontroller.

```
MyMatchesVC *myMatchesVC = [[MyMatchesVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMatchesVC" bundle:nil];
HomeVC *home = [[HomeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeVC" bundle:nil];

myMatchesVC.strType = pushType;
[((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController) setViewControllers:@[home, myMatchesVC] animated:YES];
```

for Go to you home viewcontroller by edit HomeVC to your home